# my preloader doesn't appear first on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, preloader

i have a page i made with skrollr, a jquery plugin to animate stuff on scroll. as i load the page, i see all my animation elements scattered around the page and after just a split second they go back in place.

i think it's ugly, that's why i decided to implement a fake preloader, which works this way:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $('body').addClass('loaded');
}, 2500);
```

it's fake because the animation elements are pure css, it's not about image preloading. i just need about 2 seconds of this fake preloading thing to appear before everything else. it's a matter of what is loaded first and i can't figure out how to make the preloader `div`, css and javascript to load before everything else..

my page layout is like this

in `<head>` i have the css file, in the `body` first thing i have the preloader html and right before the `</body>` i have these scripts:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/build/production.min.js"></script>
```

inside `production.min.js` i have my function for the preloader and then the rest of the javascripts that make the plugin work.

i even tried moving jquery to the top followed by the preloader function in an inline script but it didn't work. the page is loaded messy for a second and then it gets in place.

what am i doing wrong?
thanks!!

Comment: What is the intended effect of adding that class to the `<body>` tag?

Comment: yes.. that's what triggers the loader to disappear (css)

Comment: Could you replicate the issue in an example plunk or jsfiddle?